# Novice developer - Trouble with php contact form templates - probably something dumb

Tags: javascript, php, email, phpmailer, contacts

I am a novice developer and for some reason I have never been able to get a php contact form to function properly. I've tried templates from bootstrapious and reusable forms but I've never been able to get them to work. My ultimate goal is to have a form with recaptcha but I can't get just a regular old form to work. Here are the codes from my latest attempt. I've been working on this for days and I feel like I'm missing something small and stupid. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Contact Form Tutorial by Bootstrapious.com</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 py-5">

                <h1>Contact form Tutorial from <a href="http://bootstrapious.com">Bootstrapious.com</a></h1>

                <p class="lead">This is a demo for our tutorial dedicated to crafting working Bootstrap contact form with PHP and AJAX background.</p>
                <p class="lead">This file uses PHPMailer to send the emails.</p>


                <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact-2.php" role="form">

                    <div class="messages"></div>

                    <div class="controls">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
                                    <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required. Contact form template by <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form" target="_blank">Bootstrapious</a>.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div><!-- /.8 -->

        </div> <!-- /.row-->

    </div> <!-- /.container-->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js" integrity="sha256-dHf/YjH1A4tewEsKUSmNnV05DDbfGN3g7NMq86xgGh8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="contact-2.js"></script>

</body>
```

PHP

```
<?php
/*
THIS FILE USES PHPMAILER INSTEAD OF THE PHP MAIL() FUNCTION
*/

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

/*
*  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
*/

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$fromEmail = 'uprightjared@gmail.com';
$fromName = 'Demo contact form';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendToEmail = 'uprightjared@gmail.com';
$sendToName = 'Demo contact form';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 
'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back 
to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try 
again later';

/*
*  LET'S DO THE SENDING
*/

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by 
error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

$emailTextHtml = "<h1>You have a new message from your contact form</h1> 
<hr>";
$emailTextHtml .= "<table>";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailTextHtml .= "<tr><th>$fields[$key]</th><td>$value</td></tr>";
    }
}
$emailTextHtml .= "</table><hr>";
$emailTextHtml .= "<p>Have a nice day,<br>Best,<br>Ondrej</p>";

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
$mail->addAddress($sendToEmail, $sendToName); // you can add more addresses 
by simply adding another line with $mail->addAddress();
$mail->addReplyTo($from);

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->msgHTML($emailTextHtml); // this will also create a plain-text version 
of the HTML email, very handy


if(!$mail->send()) {
    throw new \Exception('I could not send the email.' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
}

$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
 // $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
 echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {

// init the validator
// validator files are included in the download package
// otherwise download from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

$('#contact-form').validator();


// when the form is submitted
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

    // if the validator does not prevent form submit
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "contact-2.php";

        // POST values in the background the the script URL
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and 
apply it to the 
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert- 
dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    // empty the form
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
});
```

Comment: It would help if you had something more to go by than "trouble" and "get them to work"? If unsure how to debug, you should dial back on the JavaScript/AJAX submission and use a plain old form POST for now. Else concretize error messages, HTTP request/responses, and JS console errors. Otherwise remains unlikely to get answered.

Comment: What kind of error messages are you getting?

Comment: For a basic form that works (and uses latest PHPMailer), check out the [contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps). Get that working, *then* start doing JS stuff.

Comment: I'm not getting an error message. When I click send it just doesn't do anything. When I'v tried other forms it says "sending..." but never sends

Comment: I tried the example synchro provided and that has a lot of bugs in it and didn't work. I tried another template and got "No input file specified."

Comment: Start with a super simple example to send the email in php. Do not even read stuff from your html form. Then work your way up from there. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial